# Task not Serializable - Spark Java

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I'm getting the Task not serializable error in Spark. I've searched and tried to use a static function as suggested in some posts, but it still gives the same error.

Code is as below:

```
public class Rating implements Serializable {
    private SparkSession spark;
    private SparkConf sparkConf;
    private JavaSparkContext jsc;
    private static Function<String, Rating> mapFunc;

    public Rating() {
        mapFunc = new Function<String, Rating>() {
            public Rating call(String str) {
                return Rating.parseRating(str);
            }
        };
    }

    public void runProcedure() { 
        sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Filter Example").setMaster("local");
        jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Word Count")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate();        

        JavaRDD<Rating> ratingsRDD = spark.read().textFile("sample_movielens_ratings.txt")
                .javaRDD()
                .map(mapFunc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rating newRating = new Rating();
        newRating.runProcedure();
    }
}
```

The error gives:
[image]

How do I solve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clearly `Rating` cannot be `Serializable`, because it contains references to Spark structures (i.e. `SparkSession`, `SparkConf`, etc.) as attributes.

The problem here is in

```
JavaRDD<Rating> ratingsRD = spark.read().textFile("sample_movielens_ratings.txt")
            .javaRDD()
            .map(mapFunc);
```

If you look at the definition of `mapFunc`, you're returning a `Rating` object.

```
mapFunc = new Function<String, Rating>() {
    public Rating call(String str) {
        return Rating.parseRating(str);
    }
};
```

This function is used inside a `map` (a *transformation* in Spark terms). Because the *transformations* are executed directly into the worker nodes and not in the driver node, their code **must be** serializable. This forces Spark to try serialize the `Rating` class, but it is not possible.

Try to extract the features you need from `Rating`, and placing them in a different class that does not own any Spark structure. Finally, use this new class as return type of your `mapFunc` function.

Comment: Separating Rating and the procedure into two classes worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition you have to be sure to **not include non-serializable** variables in your class like *JavaSparkContext* and *SparkSession*. if you need to include them you should define like this:

```
private transient JavaSparkContext sparkCtx;
private transient SparkSession spark;
```

Good luck.

Comment: This little nugget just saved me. Until seeing this, I just couldn't get a clear idea of what was going wrong. So after working in circles for a good day, I finally get it. Thanks