# "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, serialization

I'm trying to run the following simple Spark code:

```
package com.bdg.try.graph_api;
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark;
import com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SparkStreamingApplication {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkStreamingApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SparkStreamingApplication.class, args);
    SparkStreamingApplication main = new SparkStreamingApplication();
    main.run();
}
private void run(){
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("spark://192.168.xx.xx:7077")
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.xx.xx:27017/database.test_spark")
        .config("spark.database.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.xx.xx:27017/database.test_spark")
        .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
        .appName("SparkTest")
        .getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

// Create a custom WriteConfig
Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
writeOverrides.put("collection", "spark");
writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "majority");
WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(writeOverrides);

// Create a RDD of 10 documents
JavaRDD<Document> sparkDocuments = jsc.parallelize(asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)).map
    (new Function<Integer, Document>() {
        public Document call(final Integer i) throws Exception {
            return Document.parse("{spark: " + i + "}");
        }
    });

System.out.println("collection : "+writeOverrides);
MongoSpark.save(sparkDocuments, writeConfig);
spark.stop();
}
}
```

Log Exception here :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
at com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication.run(GraphApiApplication.java:60)
at com.bdg.ebdesk.graph_api.GraphApiApplication.main(GraphApiApplication.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bdg.try.graph_api.GraphApiApplication
```

**[UPDATE]**
next, I'm add `implements java.io.Serializable`, but Error Log above :

```
2017-07-07 09:27:19.238 ERROR 4369 --- [ffle-server-3-1] o.a.s.n.server.TransportRequestHandler   : Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 7048300146537589013
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RetrieveSparkProps$
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Here 'jsc' is the JavaSparkContext object I'm using. As far as I know, JavaSparkContext is not a Serializable object and one should not use it inside any functions which will be sent to the Spark workers.

Now, what I'm not able to understand is, how the instance of JavaSparkContext is being sent to the workers? What should I change in my code to avoid such scenario?

Comment: you need to collect `sparkDocuments` to driver node. Since you haven't collected, they are executing in worker nodes.

Comment: Here is a similer issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480311/task-not-serializable-spark-java
The problem is that your defined anonymous class is not serializable.