# Task not serialisable error in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, rdd

I have the two variables below:

```scala
var rddPair1 : Array[(String, String)] = Array((0000003,杉山______ 26 F),
    (0000005,崎村______ 50 F), (0000007,梶川______ 42 F))
```

and

```scala
var rddPair2 : Array[(String, String)] = Array((0000005,82 79 16 21 80),
    (0000001,46 39 8 5 21), (0000004,58 71 20 10 6), (0000009,60 89 33 18 6),
    (0000003,30 50 71 36 30), (0000007,50 2 33 15 62))
```

The code below joins these 2 variables with a full outer join:

```scala
var emp = rddPair1.first._2.replaceAll("\\S", "*") //emp:String = ***** ** *
rddPair1.fullOuterJoin(rddPair2).map {
  case (id, (left, right)) =>
    (id,left.getOrElse(emp)+" "+ right)
}.collect()
```

And I get an error like the below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370)
  ... 56 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@4d87e7f3)
        - field (class: $iw, name: spark, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@65af4162)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@7da837af)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@54d0724f)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@389ae8f1)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@55ecf961)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@428c9250)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@d931617)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@2625c1cc)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@1231e446)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@27dbe9a3)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@63ad2a0f)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@203f41d7)
        - field (class: $line19.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line19.$read, $line19.$read@46a9af36)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line19$read, type: class $line19.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@19d118d5)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@5dac488d)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@1bba5848)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4f1a6259)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@25712d03)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@750c242e)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@ad038f8)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4ba64e36)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@223f8c82)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@ba1f5d1)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4355f7b6)
        - field (class: $line22.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line22.$read, $line22.$read@44535df8)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line22$read, type: class $line22.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@32e14e55)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@5a78e7e3)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@28736857)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@16be6b36)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@211e1b51)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@1cce2194)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@7b31281b)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@63c9017b)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@e343477)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@3a182eaf)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@131af11d)
        - field (class: $line24.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line24.$read, $line24.$read@7cb39309)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line24$read, type: class $line24.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@282afe91)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@33592b53)
        - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $anonfun$1, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
  ... 65 more
```

And this is my desired output :

> ```
> 0000001 ********** ** * 46 39 8  5  21
> 0000004 ********** ** * 58 71 20 10 6
> 0000009 ********** ** * 60 89 33 18 6
> 0000003 杉山______ 26 F 30 50 71 36 30
> 0000007 梶川______ 42 F 50 2  33 15 62
> ```

Comment: How you define RDDs `rddPair1` and `rddPair1`? Now,  `rddPair1` and `rddPair1` are two arrays instead of RDDS.

Comment: Check that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480311/task-not-serializable-spark-java/49510969#49510969 Good Luck.

Comment: @ChristianMata That post is used in java spark. But I'm using scala spark. :(

Comment: @Mahdi It is RDD. The join statement still works when I pass a hard string into it

Comment: to me, your statement works fine, in spark-shell. what is the environment that you execute the code?

Comment: @Mahdi 
My usage environment is also spark-shell. Spark-2.4.3 and hadoop 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The solution is suitable in both envoironments.

Regards.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much for this.